# Scrolling overflowed divs with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I know there are similar posts, but I couldn't find a single answer in any of them that has worked for me. I want the new messages to scroll to the bottom but it's not doing it.

Here's my script show_messages.js:

I have a div named  'show-messages' set with overflow: auto

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // grab id from html attribute
    var uid = $('#message').attr('name');

    setInterval(function() {
        // load messages with userid
        $('#show-messages').load('show_messages.php?uid=' + uid);
        $("#show-messages").scrollTop = $("#show-messages").scrollHeight;

    }, 500 );
});
```

Does anyone have any ideas would could be causing to not scroll down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`scrollTop`](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) is a function of jQuery objects but you are calling it like a property. However, `scrollHeight` is not, but it's a property on the HTML Element. To access the (first) HTML element from a jQuery object, use `$()[0]`.

Also, you should cal it after the `load` finishes

```
$('#show-messages').load('show_messages.php?uid=' + uid, function () {
    $("#show-messages").scrollTop( $("#show-messages")[0].scrollHeight );
});
```

Comment: Thank your solution worked! but it took a second before it loaded up. Then I noticed Adam's answer, which I liked but didn't work because scrollTop is a function(as you said), so I combined yours with his, and it instantly loads up. Thank you, also I did notice your edit, which is exactly what I did thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use .scrollTop function as a callback of load methods.

```
$('#show-messages').load('show_messages.php?uid=' + uid, function () {
        $("#show-messages").scrollTop($("#show-messages")[0].scrollHeight);
});
```